# Let $f:[-3,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Show that there is $c \in [-3,1]$ such that $|f'(c)|\geq \frac{5}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[-3,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function such that $f([-3,1])=[-5,5]$. Show that there is $c \in [-3,1]$ such that $|f'(c)|\geq \frac{5}{2}$

I tried to use Mean Value Theorem, but since I don't have $f(-3)$ nor $f(1)$ then how can I proceed? I can see that if it were $f(-3)=-5$ and $f(1)=5$ then I would find some $c$ where $|f'(c)|=\frac{5}{2}$ by MVT.

Comment: You are soooooo close. Think about what you just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your notation I presume that range of $f(x)$  for $x\in [-3,1]$ is $[-5,5]$.

Thus we **must have** some $a,b$ (consider $a\lt b$, the result is unaltered) so that $[a,b] \subset [-3,1]$ and that $f(a) = -5$ and $f(b) = 5$ and since $[a,b]$ is subset of $[-3,1]$ we have that $|b-a| \le |1-(-3)| = 4$.

So apply Lagrange MVT on $[a,b]$ for $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$, that we must have $c$ so that

$$|f'(c)| = \left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right| = \frac{10}{|b-a|} \ge \frac{10}{4} = \frac{5}{2}$$

Note that we can have $a>b$ without altering the result.

Comment: Your second paragraph is false. It could be $f(a)= 5,f(b)=-5.$ Also we don't know $|b-a| < 4.$

Comment: She I meant to say $f(a)=5$ and $f(B)=-5$. And then we have two cases $a\gt b$ or $a\lt b$. The result is same. Also as already said, since $[a,b]$ is subset of $[-3,1]$ so $|b-a|\le 4$

Answer (score 1):

There must be *some* $x_1\in [-3, 1]$ such that $f(x_1) = -5$. Similarily, there must be *some* $x_2\in [-3, 1]$ such that $f(x_2) = 5$. Now use the mean value theorem on those two values, together with some inequalities, like $|x_2-x_1|\leq 4$.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that if it were $f(-3)=-5$ and $f(1)=5$ then I would find some $c$ where $|f'(c)|=\frac{5}{2}$ by MVT.

**Hint**: and if it doesn't happen in the endpoints, then it has to happen somewhere *in* the interval (which isn't as long!); meaning there exist $a,b \in [-3,1]$ such that $f(a)=-5$ and $f(b)=5$. Now assume $a<b$ and apply the MVT on $[a,b]$, the other case is similar.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: @Sobolev if the image is $[-5,5]$, then $f$ takes these extreme values somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b$ in $[-3,1]$ such that $f(a)=-5$ and $f(b)=5$ and assume  that $a$ or $b$ are not endpoints of the interval $[-3,1]$ (otherwise you already shown what happens). Then there is $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that
$$|f'(c)|=\frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{|b-a|}=\frac{10}{|b-a|}> \frac{10}{4}=\frac{5}{2}.$$
Moroever, since $a$ or $b$ are in $(-3,1)$ it follows that $f'$ attains the value $0$ and, by [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), $|f'|$ assume any value in the interval $[0,5/2]\subset[0,|f'(c)|]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f([−3,1])=[−5,5].$ there exists $x,y\in [-3,1]$ such that $|f(x)=5$ and $f(y) =-5$

> We have, $x\neq y$ assume $x<y$ then  $|x-y|\le 1-(-3)=4$ and   by MVT there exists $c\in(x,y)$  such that

$$f'(c)= \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} =\frac{5-(-5)}{x-y} =\frac{10}{x-y}$$

That is $$|f'(c)|= \frac{10}{|x-y|}\ge\frac{10}{|1+3|} =\frac52$$

Comment: I don't know why you added comment and then posted very similar answer to those already present.